# Calculate a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to calculate the follwing integral:
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{\sin^2 z}dz$$
where $\gamma$ is the circle of the center $0$ and radius $R=\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ (in the positive direction). 
I tried the parametrization $z(t)=Re^{i t}$ where $t\in [0,2 \pi]$, but the integral got more complicated.

I also tried to write the integral as follows
$$-2\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{\cos 2z-1}dz$$
in order to use Cauchy's formula but it's not obvious.

Comment: Do you know the Residue Theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integrand has 3 double poles at $0$ and $\pm \pi$. Near the pole at $0$, 
$$\begin{cases}
e^z &\sim 1 + z + O(z^2)\\
\sin(z)^2 &\sim z^2 + O(z^4)
\end{cases}
\implies
\frac{e^z}{\sin(z)^2} \sim \frac1{z^2} + \frac1z + O(1)$$

By [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), only the term $\frac1z$ contributes to your integral. Its contribution to the integal equals to
$2\pi i$. By a similar argument, the contribution form the poles at $\pm \pi$ are $2\pi i e^{\pm \pi}$ ($\sin(z)^2$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$). This means your integral equals to

$$2\pi i( 1 + e^{\pi} + e^{-\pi})$$

Comment: Well how did you calculate the Resudue of $f$ in both $z=+\pi$ and $z=-\pi$

Comment: @AnasBOUALII Let $z = x \pm \pi$. Since $\sin(z)^2$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$, $\frac{e^z}{\sin(z)^2} = \frac{e^x}{\sin(x)^2}e^{\pm \pi}$. This means the residue of $\frac{e^z}{\sin(z)^2}$ at $z = \pm \pi \iff x = 0$ is the residue at $z = 0$ multiply by $e^{\pm \pi}$.